# jQuery data function usage with keywords

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-data, jquery-attributes

My HTML:

```
 <a id="link" class="linkRedirect" data-href="">Download Link</a>
```

I am getting incorrect value for $("#link").data("href") when clicked multiple times.

Click Handler:

```
 $(document).on("click", "#link", function (e) {
            var url = $("#link").data("href");
            //check validation
            if(true) location.href = url;
 });
```

The file in the url will be downloaded only if the session is valid.

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle showing the problem?

Comment: what you are expecting from `if(true) location.href = url;`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4nbtn/ works like expected.

Comment: $("#link").attr("href"); would be better...

Comment: @crack Its a download link. When user clicks, some token validation is done; if success download the file.

Comment: @Gourav If I use href directly, I cannot validate the token.

Answer (score 0):

You could rather use it like this:

```
<a id="link" class="linkRedirect" rel="somelink">Download Link</a>
```

then ins your jquery, use this:

```
 $(document).on("click", "#link", function (e) {
            var url = $("#link").attr("rel");
            //check validation
            if(url)//apply whatever check you want
             location.href = url;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery code is really weird. Anyway check with that:

```
$('#link').click(function(){
  var url = $("#link").attr("data-href"); 
  if(url){
    window.location = url;
  }
});
```

I didn't test it but that would work better than your code :)

Comment: Thanks. It works. The issue occurs when data function is used

Answer (score 0):

Got the problem. When I renamed attribute data-href to data-url, the issue was solved.

```
$("#link").data("href")
```

The value obtained was that of href attribute and not data-href.